# Laravel Eloquent 5 Tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have 5 tables.

```
Users
Categories
Products
Product_categories
Order Details
```

A user purchases an an item and in my order details table I store the quantities etc.

I wanted to return all items that are of the main category = 'Testing' via the user.

```
$user = Auth::user();

return $user->items();
```

I have the following relationship on my user model.

```
public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\OrderDetail','user_id')->selectRaw('item_description,count(quantity) as count')->where('item_description','<>','Carriage')->groupBy('item_id')->get();
    }
```

I know I've not associated the the categories table here but I'm wondering how I would pull all the users order details where item category is "testing". The item can be related to many categories hence the product_categories table.

I'm not after someone writing the answer I'd like to know where I start to look at linking these via the model?

Would I be right in saying I have to do a function within my model relation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your requirements & structure, your table should be structured like this:

```
users
    id
    name
    ...

categories
    id
    name
    ...

products
    id
    name
    cost
    ...

category_product
    id
    category_id
    product_id

order_details
    id
    user_id
    cost
    ...

product_order_detail
    id
    product_id
    order_detail_id
```

Your models should be structured like this:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function orderDetails()
    {
      return $this->hasMany(OrderDetail::class);
    }
}

class Product extends Model
{
    public function categories()
    {
      return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'category_product');
    }

    public function orderDetails()
    {
      return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class, 'product_order_detail');
    }
}

class Category extends Model
{
    public function product()
    {
      return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'category_product');
    }
}

class OrderDetail extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function products()
    {
      return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_order_detail');
    }
}
```

and to fetch all the items / products who belongs to the category named `Testing` and belongs to the user, who've ordered it:

```
$items = Product::whereHas('categories', function($q) {
                    $q->where('name', '=', 'Testing');
                })->whereHas('orderDetails', function($q) use($user) {
                    $q->whereHas('user', function($q) use($user) {
                        $q->where('id', $user->id);
                    });
                })->get();
```

Hope this helps!